# PostgreSql: duplicate pkey error when inserting a new records to a restored database's table

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I used the commands `pg_dump` and `psql` to backup my production DB and restore it into my development server.
Now when I try to simply insert a new record to one of my tables I get the following error message:

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "communication_methods_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(13) already exists.

How come that the id is already in use? I need to update something in order to have the id increment counter back on the right track?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like the sequences used to do the primary key for each table are not on the correct value. It is interesting that pg_dump did not include a sequence setval at the end of it (I believe it is supposed to).

Postgres recommends the following process to correct sequences: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fixing_Sequences

Essentially, it takes you through identifying all your sequences and creating a sql script to run to set them to 1 more than your inserted value's ids.